# Texmaker doesn't switch pdf's

Tags: texmaker

I'm using Texmaker on a Linux machine and working with multiple .tex files. When I compile a file, the internal viewer shows the pdf, as expected. However, when I switch to a different .tex file, the internal viewer doesn't switch to the corresponding pdf (although this pdf was previously compiled).

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you prefer an automatic solution or would you be fine with using the "view pdf" button?

Comment: That is an almost optimal approach. By pressing F7 also switches pdfs.